# Как добавить программу в автозагрузку c помощью батника на Windows?

Tags: windows, bat, автозагрузка

Подскажите как добавить программу в автозагрузку с помощью **батника** (или вообще каким-то иным  способом), только кроме добавления ярлыка в папку "Автозагрузка".

Comment: Записать строку запуска программы в реестр, например... или создать задание в планировщике на событие входа в систему...

Comment: Как именно это сделать "Записать строку запуска программы в реестр"?

Comment: Откройте окно командного процессора и выполните команду `REG ADD /?`. Там всё написано. Составьте нужную строку запуска и выполните её в своём батнике.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!